# Linux freezes at login

Tags: linux, arch-linux

I have arch on my laptop and it worked until now.

But it ran out of juice in my backpack and I can't login since.

When I boot and get to the login prompt it freezes.
And I can get into recovery mode, but when I run `login` it freezes too.

When it freezes there is some text including (those implying failure):

```
ucsi_acpiUSBC000:00: ucsi_ack: failed
ucsi_acpi USBC000:00: PPM init failed (-110)
```

and I can continue to type but it just doesn't do anything.

How can I get back into my system?

**EDIT:** it works now but I'm not quite sure why...
So what I did was boot a bunch of times and type my credentials as quick as I could because login would only lock up after those texts show up. Then I did a clean `reboot` once I got in and now its working like a charm again.

I really can't believe that those texts where interfering with my login. There must have been something I've done on accident right?